# What is the equivalent of "QT_CONFIG()" of Qt for c++ in PyQt5 (for Python)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am building a drawing app as seen in this tutorial:
http://www.newthinktank.com/2018/07/qt-tutorial-5-paint-app/
The difference is that this is made in c++ with Qt and I am trying to translate it in Python Qt. However, I cannot find any equivalent for "# if QT_CONFIG" to Python in the code:

```
#if QT_CONFIG(printdialog)
 
    // Can be used to print
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
 
    // Open printer dialog and print if asked
    QPrintDialog printDialog(&printer, this);
    if (printDialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
        QPainter painter(&printer);
        QRect rect = painter.viewport();
        QSize size = image.size();
        size.scale(rect.size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
        painter.setViewport(rect.x(), rect.y(), size.width(), size.height());
        painter.setWindow(image.rect());
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, image);
    }
#endif // QT_CONFIG(printdialog)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct translation of `QT_CONFIG` as it is a preprocessing command used by the C++ compiler, and that concept does not exist in python.

So if it can be done is a logical or functional translation, the objective of this command is to find out if the Qt library used to compile enabled the flag for the printsupport submodule, which in the case of PyQt5 implies that the QtPrintSupport module exists, like this just use a try-except:

```py
def print(self):
    try:
        from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter, QPrintDialog
    except ImportError as e:
        print("not print support")
    else:
        printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
        printDialog = QPrintDialog(printer, self)
        if printDialog.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            painter = QPainter(printer)
            rect = painter.viewport()
            size = self.image.size()
            size.scale(rect.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            painter.setViewport(rect.x(), rect.y(), size.width(), size.height())
            painter.setWindow(self.image.rect())
            painter.drawImage(0, 0, self.image)
```

**Note:** By default the officially provided library always comes with the printdialog flag enabled by default so you could simply ignore the `QT_CONFIG(printdialog)` in your translation, unless you have compiled the Qt with that flag disabled, and then use that Qt to compile PyQt5.